# Truncations of orientals

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $n,m $ be naturals such that $n >m$ and $(-)_{\leq m}$ the left adjoint of the embedding of
m-categories into n-categories, which we call m-truncation.
Is there a canonical presentation of the m-truncation of the n-th oriental $O(n)_{\leq m}$
as a colimit of orientals $O(k)$ for $k \leq m$?

For example $O(n)_{\leq 0} \simeq O(0)$ and $O(n)_{\leq 1} \simeq [n] \simeq O(1) \times_{O(0)} O(1) \times_{O(0)} ... \times_{O(0)} \times O(1).$
Is there a general pattern extending these examples?